# Reference to Outlook becomes missing, leading to Excel error: Unable to Load DLL In Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a macro to import data from Access to Excel. One component of the import is to prompt the user to see if they would like to email the workbook. If yes, then a new email opens with the workbook attached. To accomplish this, I referenced the Outlook 14.0 object library.

After a few refreshes of the data from Access, I began to get run time errors which I have since fixed. However, now I get a notice that Excel is "Unable to Load DLL" when I try to open a module to modify it.

When I look at the libraries referenced, the Outlook library indicates that it is missing. I am unable to deselect the library in Excel 2010 and have to open the workbook on another computer that is running Excel 2016, where everything works. Once I deselect the library and save it, I can use the macro again in 2010 and modify the code.

Comment: If you are going to be using this across multiple computers/platforms, then consider [late binding your outlook reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939197/convert-early-binding-vba-to-late-binding-vba-excel-to-outlook-contacts)

Comment: Thank you JNevill, that seems to work perfectly!