# Run same macro in different versions of Excel / Outlook / Word

Tags: excel, vba, outlook-addin, late-binding

I generate reports to send to different branches. I run a macro that creates protected reports (*.xlsm). These reports have a space for comments for the Branch Managers, with a "send Comments" button that run this macro below.

I suggested the following [references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uZVd.png) to add if the macro does not work.

The Branch Managers have different versions of MS Office (Excel, Outlook, etc.) on their laptops. When they try to Run, it shows errors, such as: "Error in Loadind DLL"; [Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnLia.png), etc.

What should be done on the Branch Managers side to run this Macro?

```
Sub CommentsEmail()

Dim template As Workbook
Dim dashboard As Worksheet
Dim comments As Worksheet
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim mymail As Outlook.mailItem
Dim objSel As Word.Selection
Dim commentsrange As Range
Dim branch As String
Dim Sendto As String

UpdateScreen = False

Shell ("Outlook")

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set mymail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set template = ActiveWorkbook
Set dashboard = template.Worksheets("Dashboard")
Set comments = template.Worksheets("Comments")
branch = dashboard.Cells(1, 25)
Sendto = comments.Cells(2, 10)
Set commentsrange = comments.Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(52, 4))

template.Activate


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'OutMail.Display
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

Set objSel = wordDoc.Windows(1).Selection

        'construct the body of the email here
        With objSel

            'first text
            .InsertAfter "Dear All," & vbCrLf
            .Move wdParagraph, 1

            'second text
            .InsertAfter vbCrLf & "See below the Comments for Flash Indicator - " & branch & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            .Move wdParagraph, 1

            'copy a range and paste a picture
            commentsrange.Copy ''again, you need to modify your target range
            .PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
            .Move wdParagraph, 1

            .InsertAfter vbCrLf & "Let us know of any questions." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            .Move wdParagraph, 1

            .InsertAfter vbCrLf & "Kind Regards," & vbCrLf
        End With

        OutMail.To = OutMail.To & ";" & Sendto

        With OutMail

         .Subject = "Comments on Flash Indicator Results - " & branch
         .Attachments.Add (ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
         .Display
        End With

On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing


        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
        Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Is this still early binding? If yes, I am totally lost.

```
Sub CommentsEmail2()

Dim template As Workbook
Dim dashboard As Worksheet
Dim comments As Worksheet
Dim OlaApp As Object
Dim OleMail As Object

Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim xHTMLBody As String

Dim commentsrange As Range
Dim branch As String
Dim Sendto As String

UpdateScreen = False

Set template = ActiveWorkbook
Set dashboard = template.Worksheets("Dashboard")
Set comments = template.Worksheets("Comments")
Set commentsrange = comments.Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(52, 4))

branch = dashboard.Cells(1, 25)
Sendto = comments.Cells(2, 10)

template.Activate

 On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OleMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

Call createJpg(ActiveSheet.comments, commentsrange, "DashboardFile")
        TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
        xHTMLBody = "<span LANG=EN>" _
                & "<p class=style2><span LANG=EN><font FACE=Calibri SIZE=3>" _
                & "Hello, this is the data range that you want:<br> " _
                & "<br>" _
                & "<img src='cid:DashboardFile.jpg'>" _
                & "<br>Best Regards!</font></span>"
        With OleMail
            .Subject = "test"
            .HTMLBody = xHTMLBody
          .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "DashboardFile.jpg", olByValue
          .Attachments.Add (ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
            .To = " "
            .Cc = " "
            .Display
        End With




        Set OleMail = Nothing
        Set OlaApp = Nothing


        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
        Exit Sub

End Sub

Sub createJpg(SheetName As String, commentsrange As String, nameFile As String)
    Dim xRgPic As Range
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Worksheets(comments).Activate
    Set xRgPic = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(comments).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(52, 4))
    xRgPic.CopyPicture
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(comments).ChartObjects.Add(xRgPic.Left, xRgPic.Top, xRgPic.Width, xRgPic.Height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".jpg", "JPG"
    End With
    Worksheets(comments).ChartObjects(Worksheets(comments).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
Set xRgPic = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Look up how to use *late binding* instead of *early binding*. There are helpful questions already on SO.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for your help! I tried but I couldnt find a solution to paste the range as a picture, without having to open word Document.

Comment: You should be able to do that still with late binding. Maybe post your revised code?

Comment: @BigBen This last code is where I stopped. I tried to copy a range of the report and paste as an image in the email body. it says the "commentsrange" on Call createJpg(ActiveSheet.comments, commentsrange, "DashboardFile") is mismatching.

Comment: @BigBen how do I share the file with you? Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Early Binding VBA to Late Binding VBA : Excel to Outlook Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939197/convert-early-binding-vba-to-late-binding-vba-excel-to-outlook-contacts)