# Changing from Early to Late Binding

Tags: vba, outlook

I followed these instructions to convert from early to late binding:
[Convert Early Binding VBA to Late Binding VBA : Excel to Outlook Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939197/convert-early-binding-vba-to-late-binding-vba-excel-to-outlook-contacts)

The code was working with early binding but now comes up with

```
Run-time error '5': invalid procedure call or argument
```

on the following line:

```
Set SentItemsFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olfolderinbox).Parent.Folders("Sent Items")
```

I tried

```
dim olfolderinbox as object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting from early to late binding you also have to change named enumerations to their actual values.

olFolderInbox is part of the [OlDefaultFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders) enumeration.
Its value is 6.

Changing your line to

```
Set SentItemsFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, 6).Parent.Folders("Sent Items")
```

will fix the problem as long as `myRecipient` is correct.